# Decompiling Java classes then recompiling?

Tags: java, class, compilation

I have a .Jar file that I've de-compiled using JD-GUI. I've made a couple of changes on two of the .java files that were .class before getting de-compiled. I would now like to re-compile those two files back into .class format although javac comes back with tons of errors everytime I try. Could someone please explain a simple way to re-compile the files perhaps?

```
$    javac ChangedFile.java
```

Tons of errors like this:

```
java:170: error: cannot find symbol
```

and

```
symbol:   method getNotAfter()
location: variable paramObject of type Object
```

Comment: Try to recompile decompiled classes without any your changes first. If you can't do it, the rest is fruitless.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix the code so it will compile.  This may be because decompiling is not fool proof or because it was originally compiled using code you don't have.